# Warning when Attempting to Dismiss View Controller (Modal within a Modal)

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

When my iOS app launches for the first time, I automatically open a "welcome" modal like this:

```
UIViewController *intro = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"intro"];

intro.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

//Show the modal
[self presentViewController:intro animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Inside that modal, the user is instructed to link the app to Dropbox. They tap a button that fires this:

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
```

This is a Dropbox SDK method that opens a Dropbox authentication UIWebView in **another modal** that looks like this: http://d.pr/i/6ZnC

Once they sign in, the modal automatically animates closed.

I then try to close the original intro modal with this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I get this warning and **the modal does not close**:

> Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <PPIntroViewController: 0xf296ab0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Here's what I've tried:

1. I put an artificial delay right before `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to let the Dropbox modal close, but it doesn't help: `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];`
2. I've tried turning off the animation: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];` and that doesn't help either.
3. I've tried checking for the modal dismissal already in progress: `if(![self isBeingDismissed]){ ... }` and no luck.

Any ideas? How can I determine what exactly is presenting/dismissing and preventing the modal from closing?

*iOS 7 + Xcode 5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that issue. You can see this line in `DBSession+ios.m`

> [rootController presentModalViewController:navController
>   animated:YES];

So, internally they will present their authentication view controller from `self`. Already you've present your view controller from `self`. So when either they or you try to dismiss view controller from self, give this warning because it had presenting view controller. So instead of  pass self to dropBox, pass `intro` view controller.

```
[[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:intro];
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm opening the Dropbox modal from *inside* `intro`, so referring to it requires that I point to `self`, no? `intro` is up in the parent controller.

Comment: try it the other way then..  [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self.presentingViewController];       somehow the modal controller stack is being corrupted, they're not piling up cleanly..

Comment: Exact point, Where did you try to dismiss after authentication? that is how get that delegate method which is authenticated and dismissed?

Comment: I tried self.presentingViewController, but that doesn't work because my current modal (introViewController) is covering it.

Comment: I'm inside `introViewController`. I tap a button and it opens the Dropbox authentication in a modal. Signing in to Dropbox automatically dismisses the Dropbox modal and I'm back to `introViewController`.

Comment: introViewController: http://d.pr/i/w7FK
Dropbox modal (after tapping the green button): http://d.pr/i/6ZnC

Comment: Ya I already understood upto this point "I'm back to `introViewController`".. But question is when you try to dismiss `introViewController`?

Comment: I dismiss it from within one of Dropbox's delegates (after making a call to Dropbox which happens after logging into Dropbox).

Comment: Yes there is a problem. Because delegate always get called before dismissal.

Comment: You were right, iMani. Moving the modal dismissal to a button instead of a Dropbox delegate resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

From inside the introViewController rather than from in the root one.  This should call on self.presentingViewController if there is no other modal.  So I'd nest one in the completion handle block of the first

Comment: I probably wasn't clear, but I am calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` from inside `introViewController` and no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

I Found that this issue occurs if you trying to push/dismiss view controller while previous transaction (animation) in progress.

Take `NSTimer` and dismissViewController between **0.50 to 1** second. This is helpful trick so your current viewController has done its animation.

**Otherwise** not sure but try to set **NO** with `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: I tried a timer delay and turning off the animation and the error still occurs.