# Dismissing modal view controller in another modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My iPad app presents a modal view controller from which the user can choose to send an email. My issue is that this opens a new modal view controller `(MFMailComposeViewController)`, which I then can't seem to dismiss properly. [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898920/warning-when-attempting-to-dismiss-view-controller-modal-within-a-modal) describes a similar issue, but none of the suggestions in that thread worked for me.

My initial view controller brings up the modal VC using a storyboard segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
```

The modal view controller calls the following method when a UIButton is pressed to bring up the iOS default mail composer VC:

```
- (IBAction)sendWithMail
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *composeMail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    composeMail.mailComposeDelegate = self.presentingController;

    [self presentViewController:composeMail animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Here, `self.presentingController` is a reference to the initial view controller, which conforms to the `<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>` protocol. When the user has finished writing the email, the delegate method in my initial VC is called. Now I need to close the mail composer view controller and/or my own modal view controller, depending on the result. So I wrote a method in the initial VC like this:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        {
            break;
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        {
            [self updateStatusMessage:@"Mail saved."];
            break;
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            [self updateStatusMessage:@"Mail sent."];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
            break;
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        {
            [self updateStatusMessage:@"Mail failed."];
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is that the mail composer should always close, but the modal view controller should close only if the mail was sent successfully. But this doesn't work: when the mail is sent, the app crashes. The only log output is `(lldb)` and Xcode highlights the return line of main.m in green with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=...)`.

If I don't try to close the mail composer, and just call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];` regardless of the result, then both the composer and my modal view controller close and there is no problem. But this is not the behaviour I want.

I've also tried `self.presentingViewController` instead of just `self` in the dismiss calls, but that doesn't help.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about how view controllers interact, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

iOS 7 + Xcode 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just implement MFMailComposeViewController delegate method this way.

```
 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }
    [[controller presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
        {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
   }];
```

}

Comment: Fantastic – that works! Thank you so much! Can you possibly explain why my version was crashing?

Comment: @deltacrux Wecome. You can also put process view while mailComposer being dismissed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean by that. Can you post the code please? Do you know what caused the crash in my original code?

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as correct, but I'd still be interested if someone could explain why it works and my original code doesn't.

Comment: @deltacrux In your code, first you dismiss mailComposeSheet in any case. and then you check that if mail is sent then dismiss your view controller. Actually after dismiss your mailComposer, you can’t get any action and you got a warning like :

“ Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <MailViewController: 0x10c59a4d0> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress! “

That’s why your code goes into bad access state.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{


    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        {
            break;
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        {
            [self updateStatusMessage:@"Mail saved."];
            break;
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            [self updateStatusMessage:@"Mail sent."];
          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        {
            [self updateStatusMessage:@"Mail failed."];
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }

              [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm after. I only want to dismiss my modal view controller if the message was sent successfully.

Comment: No, that still doesn't do it. Now the mail compose view doesn't dismiss when the mail isn't sent.

Comment: Vimi Patel's answer does exactly what I want. Now I'd just like to understand why my original code doesn't work.